# hibernate validator and WAS 8.5

Tags: java, spring, validation, websphere, hibernate-validator

I am also facing an issue with `hibernate-validator 5.0.0` and `WAS 8.5` .  `@safeHTML`  annotation does not work. There are no errors but the validations are not enforced.
 It works in `TOMCAT`  but not in `WAS 8.5`.

It's a `Rest` service using `SPRING 4`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
  public void fetch(@Valid  @RequestBody SampleVO sampleVO,
  BindingResult result) throws Exception {

 LOGGER.debug("Incoming VO "+sampleVO);
 LOGGER.debug("Result after Hibernate Validation      "+String.valueOf(result.hasErrors()));
 if (result.hasErrors()) {
 for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
 LOGGER.error("Validation Error: {}", error.getDefaultMessage());
 }
 throw new Exception(""Validation Error");
 }
 }

 Sample VO:
 public class SampleVO {

 private Integer sampleId;
 private Long sampleType;

 @SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE)
 private String sampleTypeID;
 }
```